# Comparing a Factorial and a Perfect Power

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

Let us define the following recurrence relations as so. $$a_1=6, a_{n+1}=a_n!$$
$$b_1=6, b_{n+1}=6^{b_n}$$

So, which of the following is larger? $a_{b_2}$ or $b_{a_2}$?

To clarify, I am trying to compare $6^{6^{6^{6^6\dots}}}$ ($720$ times) and $(((6!)!)!)!\dots$($46656$ times)

While I tried to use a calculator to determine which is larger, the values were too large for me to compute.

Their log values proved difficult to compare as well.

Wolframalpha did not prove much help(see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E6%5E$) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((6)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!))

Normally it is true that $a_n$ is far smaller then $b_n$, but because $b_2$ is far larger than $a_2$, I find it hard to determine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears that the sequences $a_{b_n}$ and $b_{a_n}$ are at least wowzer in size.  They might even be ackermanic.  It might be worth seeing what [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) might do for simplifying $a_{b_2}$.  My gut feeling is that $a_{b_2}$ is the larger of the two.  For reference, Stirlings gives $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$

Comment: @JMoravitz What is ackermanic?

Comment: A way of describing how quickly a sequence/function explodes in size.  Ronald Graham discusses it starting on page 60 of his book titled "Ramsey Theory" when talking about Shelah's improvement for the upperbound on Van Der Waerden numbers and the Hales-Jewett theorem.  My point being, the sequences get *incredibly* large *incredibly* quickly.  (*All prior proofs of HJ gave ackermanic bounds whereas Shelah improved it to wowzer bounds.  Still stupidly huge, but much much lower than it had been*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G(1)=6, G(n)=6^{G(n-1)}$ and $F(1)=6, F(n)=(F(n-1))!$.  You want to compare $G(720)$ with $F(46656)$.  We have $\log G(n)=G(n-1) \log (6)$, so $720$ applications of $\log$ makes it small.  $\log F(n)\approx F(n-1)( \log F(n-1)-1)$, so it takes about $46656$ applications of $\log$ to make it small.  $F(46656) \gg G(720)$ so much that dividing $F(46656)/G(720)$ does not make it appreciably smaller.

Comment: I don't think that I understand you. What does $720$  applications of $\log$ makes it small mean?

Comment: If you take the log of $G(720)$, then the log of that, then the log of that, and do it $720$ times, you get a reasonable sized number.  In fact, it will be close to log(6).  The point is that with large numbers just taking the log once, or a few times, is not enough to matter.  It is a coarse measure, but one that can work, to count how many applications of log are required to get a reasonable number.  This is about the number of layers in the exponential stack, so I am saying the stack for $F(46656)$ is about $46656$ layers high-much more than $720$.

Answer (score -2):

A proof by words(without math) would be -
 to get $b_{n+1}$ from $b_n$ , you multiply '$6$' $b_n$ times.
 to get $a_{n+1}$ from $a_n$ , you multiply number really higher than $6$ as $n$ increases. So, I would say, $a_n$ is greater than $b_n$ for large $n$.

As far as your question is concerned, $a_{b_2}$ is larger-
$a_{b_2}= (6^6 - 1)! = (6^6 - 1)*(6^6 - 2)....(6^6 - 120)*....$many numbers 
$b_{a_2}= (6^{6!})   = (6^6)*(6^6)....$$120$ times.

$6^6 - 120 \sim 6^6$ .
So, just by $120$ numbers in the factorial, you reach very close to $b_{a_2}$..
There are a lot more numbers after that.
From this, I would say, $a_{b_2} > b_{a_2}$

Comment: Note that $b_{a_2}$ is not $6^{6!}$. It is $6^{6^{6^{6^6\dots}}}$ $6!$ times.

Comment: Oh right sorry.. 
As far as Latex is concerned, I am new here.. I will try to improve.

Comment: Also, $a_{b_2}$ is $(((6!)!)!)!\dots$  $6^6$ times.

Comment: If you are having trouble with Latex, this may prove some help.  http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html  or http://functionspace.com/equationeditor  (be sure to add $$ to each side)